# Form data won't send using Javascript to email

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to HTML and Javascript, but I have tried to do research on how to get a form to send its information to an e-mail address when the submit button is selected. Most of my research showed that PHP is needed, but when I asked my professor, he said it can be done using only javascript and the assignment needs to be submitted that way. Below is what I am trying to get to work.

```
   <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function mailMe(form){
        Subject=document.Registry.name.value;
        location = mailto:XXXXXX@yahoo.com?subject="+Subject;
        return true;
    }

        </SCRIPT>

    <FORM NAME=“Registry” onSubmit="return mailMe(this.form)" >
            <h3><font size=6pt> Visitor Registration </font></h3>
            </br>
            Name <input type="text" name=“name”><br>
            <br>
            E-Mail Address <input type="text" name=“mail”><br>
            <br>
    <INPUT TYPE="submit"><br>
    </FORM>
```

Comment: who is your professor ! name please.. o_O

Comment: your code simply opens local mail box compose window with given subject

Comment: Did he mean using Javascript to make AJAX calls to an email service somewhere else? And... what institute does this professor belong in?

Comment: Your professor should probably not be teaching anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done using only javascript or client-side technologies.

But you can probably open a new window with a mailto link.

**Please note this won't send an e-mail, but instead open your local e-mail application to send an e-mail.**

Answer (score 1):

This is a really bad idea. You should use AJAX and PHP, this is really the better method.

If you really want your code, you have a few errors. This is correct:

```
var Subject = document.getElementById("name").value;
window.location = "mailto:XXXXXX@yahoo.com?subject=" + Subject;
```

Then you have to add an ID to the name field:

```
<input type="text" name=“name” id="name"><br>
```

But let me say that you really should use PHP mail(), because then not the client email program is used to send the mail and all is done in background.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the example below which I found at Microsoft and it worked fine. Can even be done without Javascript by simply adding the "mailto:" to the form action attribute. Also note that the form element names correspond to mailto query string parameters, i.e., "subject" and "body".

References: [Microsoft mailto Protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [RFC2368:The mailto URL scheme](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt)

Micosoft SharePoint, Adobe LiveCycle, and other middleware are able to process the emailed forms on the back end.  Or one could roll their own using Java, C#, PHP, etc. Yet, that wasn't part of the class assignment ... er ... I mean question.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="mailto:user@example.com" method="get">
<input name="subject" type="hidden" value="Message Title">

Feedback:<br/>
<textarea name=body cols="40">
Please share your thoughts here
and then choose Send Feedback.
</textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Send Feedback">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```